# Pointing client's domain to our subdomain

Tags: nameserver, cname-record, cloudflare

We have a web application online *www.exampleapp.com/* running on IIS 7.5 that we have a full control of.

We also provide customised (css, images, js, etc.) versions for some customers under subdomains e.g. *customer22.exampleapp.com/*

Now we have a growing number of customers who would like to have their domains pointing to our app. They've used 301 and 302 redirects and it has worked for a while but now some clients would like to completely mask the URL, so for example:

- *www.customer22.com/* serving content from *customer22.exampleapp.com/*
- queries *www.customer22.com/register* serving content from *customer22.exampleapp.com/register*
- etc

I know what doesn't provide url masking: iframes (url - yes, but queries - no), 301, 302, CNAME.

What changes are required to accomplish domain masking? It must also support SSL. The clients are willing to make necessary DNS changes, and we have full control over our hosting and domains (managed by cloudflare).

There are some companies which are already doing something similar, for instance https://support.classy.org/customer/portal/articles/1084002-setting-up-your-domain-masking

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but can you noit accomplish this with Site binding or aliases?

Comment: Cannot use site binding as there's a complicated setup where external IPs are mapped to internal IPs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. We are managing our domains through CloudFlare. CloudFlare allows CNAMEs at Domain root, called flattening. More info [here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/)

So our setup looks like this:

- *customer22.com* CNAME to *customer22.exampleapp.com*
- *www* CNAME to *customer22.exampleapp.com*
- No other A or CNAME

In the app we are already handling requests for particular subdomains. Now I just need to make some adjustments to handle requests from root domain and www.